# Convert fixed SMPS into variable PSU

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

While tinkering with audio amplifier chips, I occasionally find myself testing op-amps that need voltages upwards of +-32V to really push them to the limit. However, off-the-shelf variable bench PSUs that can supply both +32V and -32V seem rare, and would be extremely expensive if one could be found.

However, I have one of these - an [SMPS800RE](http://connexelectronic.com/product_info.php/cPath/25_46/products_id/142) from Connexelectronic. ([Datasheet here, PDF](http://www.connexelectronic.com/documents/SMPS800RE.pdf)). This is a high power SMPS designed for audio applications. The version I have has fixed outputs of **+50V and -50V**, and is capable of delivering **10A constant** (14A peak).

I never found a permanent use for it, and was wondering exactly how I might go about **converting it into a variable bench PSU**.

1. Would it just be a matter of feeding the output into, say, a buck converter together with some potentiometers to control the desired output?
2. ...or would I need to modify the SMPS itself, perhaps including some adjustable regulation before the output stage?

Any advice in how best to achieve this? While I've made small variable supplies out of old ATX PSUs and smaller projects, I've never tackled one quite this monstrous. So the simpler the better. But I also value efficiency, and not dying.

Comment: The problems I see with this: 50 V is **a lot** many adjustable DCDC converter modules cannot handle more than around 40 V or so. I would **not** mess/change that SMPS800RE in any way, it is **extremely** powerful, if something goes wrong it might explode. Also the 10 A maximum output current, when there is a short circuit, that can easily melt wires. For testing opamps you do not need much power so I would not use such a powerfull supply but go for something low-power.

Comment: Rather, just use two 32V supplies seperatly, and have the negative of one go to the positive of the other.

Comment: If the 50 volt supply has a common 0 volt connection it makes it trickier to do what you want without finding a decent negative voltage buck regulator. This leaves few options especially as you want to power audio stuff and noise might be problematic.

Comment: What output range do you want to achieve, from 0 to +-32, or something  like from +-15 to +- 40 ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! @AliChen - yeah, was hoping for at least 0 to +-32V.

Comment: Switching PSUs usually have limits on ranges, due to pulse-width-modulation type control and properties of magnetics. For your purpose I would go for AC-AC transformer with 25V-0-25V secondary winding, with vanilla bridge rectifier and big caps, with a variac feeding all this.